# Update only provided fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have this:

```
if(isset($_POST["Submit"])) {
$updatequery = @mysql_query("UPDATE users SET FirstName='".$_POST['firstname']."', LastName='".$_POST['lastname']."', Address='".$_POST['address']."', City='".$_POST['city']."', PostalCode='".$_POST['postalcode']."', HomePhone='".$_POST['homephone']."', AltPhone='".$_POST['altphone']."', HomeWebsite='".$_POST['homewebsite']."', EmailAddress='".$_POST['email']."', Paypal='".$_POST['paypal']."', Alertpay='".$_POST['alertpay']."', Payoneer='".$_POST['payoneer']."' WHERE Username = '".$_SESSION['Username']."'");</i>
```

Now unfortunately when a user updates their info (it's a profile page), it updates everything which means if I left the Paypal email empty (because I already had it there) it updates the Paypal email with emptiness.

How do I solve this?

Comment: First, you stop working on this code and learn about [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: You should never, ever put un-sanitised user input into a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to note, **this is a really basic example and I wouldn't recommend using this in a live environment**, but it should get you going in the right direction:-

First, create an array mapping your column names to your `$_POST` variables, eg:

```
$array = array(
  'FirstName' => 'firstname',
  'LastName' => 'lastname',
  'Address' => 'address',
  'City' => 'city'
);
```

Next, loop over your newly created `$array` and check if the value exists in your `$_POST` array, like so:

```
  $data = array();
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($_POST[$value]) && !empty($_POST[$value]) {
      $data[] = $key . '="' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$value]) . '"';
    }
  }
```

Notice the `$data` array that has been created, this stores the `column = "value"` data. You can then just implode the `$data` array into your SQL string:

```
if (!empty($data)) {
  $strSQL = 'UPDATE tbl_name SET ' . implode(', ', $data) . ' WHERE Username = "' . $_SESSION['Username'] . '"';
}
```

Which would output (with some fictional `$_POST` data):

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET FirstName="John", LastName="Doe", Address="Some Street", City="Somewhere"
```

**Just to reiterate, I would not advise that you use this code as it is. It is imperative that you validate and sanitise the user input beforehand!**

Comment: I'll check this out. Also, why not use it?

Comment: I used this code and it worked perfectly! However, it does not update information lol!

Comment: See my edit in `$strSQL` (was missing the `WHERE` clause). In response to your first comment, this is a script I threw together in a few minutes, the user input is not sanitised or validated, it is prone to errors and sql injection.

Comment: Alright it works perfectly, I was an idiot and had Email => email instead of EmailAddress => email LOL! Anyways, how should I sanitize this?

Comment: There are plenty of questions covering this topic, [here's a good one worth reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Aaaalright, that's what "Sanitizing" is, thx very much already got it covered :)

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the fields, building up an `UPDATE` statement dynamically.

Pay attention to the corner case where the user *erases* the value.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this, could you please explain?

Comment: That's a PHP problem, but maybe something like this:  `if( isset($_POST['firstname'])) { $updatequery .= " firstname = " . $_POST['firstname'] }    And, assuming your original code was not just a simplified example, pay attention to the SQL injection comments, above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = '';
if( !empty($_POST['email']) )  //if value is not empty, then update        
      $sql = ", EmailAddress = '{$_POST['email']}'";
```

Then in the query,

```
 if(isset($_POST["Submit"])) {
 $updatequery = @mysql_query("UPDATE users SET FirstName='".$_POST['firstname']."',     LastName='".$_POST['lastname']."', Address='".$_POST['address']."', City='".$_POST['city']."', PostalCode='".$_POST['postalcode']."', HomePhone='".$_POST['homephone']."', AltPhone='".$_POST['altphone']."', HomeWebsite='".$_POST['homewebsite']."' $sql , ...
```

Comment: I get where the query is but where does the first part go?

Comment: after you get the `$_POST` array, anywhere above `if(isset($_POST["Submit"])) {` should work.

Comment: $sql = ", EmailAddress = '$_POST['email'] '";

Comment: there, corrected it -- `$sql = ", EmailAddress = '{$_POST['email']}'";`

Comment: Thanks very much :) Checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

Like marc_b said: Watch out for SQL injection aqttacks. Then you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE users 
SET FirstName = case when '$firstname' = '' then FirstName else '$firstname' end, 
    LastName = ...
WHERE Username = $username
```

to avoid overriding values with empty ones